Issue filtering Notion API using Power Query M
I'm trying to get pages from my Notion database using Power Query M and am getting an error 400.  Any obvious issues here?
let
url = "https://api.notion.com/v1/databases/" & notionActionsDbId & "/query",
headers = [
    Accept = "application/json",
    #"Content-Type" = "application/json",
    Authorization = "Bearer " & notionApiKey,
    #"Notion-Version" = "2022-06-28"
],
postData = Json.FromValue({
    "filter" = {
        "property" = "Deadline",
        "date" = {
            "this_week" = {}
        }
    }
}),
response = Web.Contents(url, [
    Headers = headers,
    Content = postData
]),
jsonResponse = Json.Document(response)

in
jsonResponse
